# Parsing show command for IOX XR with TextFSM

Tags: python

Tryin to parse this output using textFSM and only to capture the IPV6 address and the Prefix (last Column)

```
  Fri Jan 17 14:47:52.532 EST
  BGP router identifier x.x.x.x, local AS number 22773
  BGP generic scan interval 60 secs
  Non-stop routing is enabled
  BGP table state: Active
  Table ID: 0xe0800000   RD version: 1838
  BGP main routing table version 1838
  BGP NSR Initial initsync version 2 (Reached)
  BGP NSR/ISSU Sync-Group versions 1838/0
  BGP scan interval 60 secs

  BGP is operating in STANDALONE mode.


  Process       RcvTblVer   bRIB/RIB   LabelVer  ImportVer  SendTblVer  StandbyVer
  Speaker            1838       1838       1838       1838        1838        1838

  Neighbor        Spk    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ  Up/Down  St/PfxRcd
  2001:578:1:0:172:17:249:18
                      0 22773  236964  229196     1838    0    0    11w2d        411
  2001:578:1:0:172:17:249:19
                      0 22773  236927  229196     1838    0    0    11w2d        411
  2001:578:2800:0:172:22:66:102
                      0 22773  114619  114616     1838    0    0    11w2d         72
  2001:578:2800:0:172:22:77:159
                      0 22773  126001  114572     1838    0    0     9w4d          8
  2001:578:2800:0:172:22:77:160
                      0 22773  126009  114560     1838    0    0    11w2d          8
```

Using this TextFSM Template but it will only dump the IP address

```
  Value NEIGHBOR (\S+)
  Value SPK (\d+)
  Value AS (\d+)
  Value MSGRCVD (\d+)
  Value MSGSENT (\d+)
  Value TBLVER (\d+)
  Value INQ (\d+)
  Value OUTQ (\d+)
  Value UPDOWN ((\S+(\s\S+)*))
  Value PFXRCD (\S+)


  Start
     ^${NEIGHBOR}
```

^${SPK}\s+${AS}\s+${MSGRCVD}\s+${MSGSENT}\s+${TBLVER}\s+${INQ}\s+${OUTQ}\s+${UPDOWN}\s+${PFXRCD}  -> Record

Not sure why it won't show me the IP address + the rest of the fields.

this show command will only dump each IP address on a line and the rest on another line, it is not an issue with screen size etc..

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `\s+` for the row preceding the IPv6 Address:

```
Value NEIGHBOR (\S+)
Value SPK (\d+)
Value AS (\d+)
Value MSGRCVD (\d+)
Value MSGSENT (\d+)
Value TBLVER (\d+)
Value INQ (\d+)
Value OUTQ (\d+)
Value UPDOWN ((\S+(\s\S+)*))
Value PFXRCD (\S+)

Start
  ^${NEIGHBOR}
  ^\s+${SPK}\s+${AS}\s+${MSGRCVD}\s+${MSGSENT}\s+${TBLVER}\s+${INQ}\s+${OUTQ}\s+${UPDOWN}\s+${PFXRCD} -> Record
```

Output:

```
NEIGHBOR, SPK, AS, MSGRCVD, MSGSENT, TBLVER, INQ, OUTQ, UPDOWN, PFXRCD
2001:578:1:0:172:17:249:18, 0, 22773, 236964, 229196, 1838, 0, 0, 11w2d, 411
2001:578:1:0:172:17:249:19, 0, 22773, 236927, 229196, 1838, 0, 0, 11w2d, 411
2001:578:2800:0:172:22:66:102, 0, 22773, 114619, 114616, 1838, 0, 0, 11w2d, 72
2001:578:2800:0:172:22:77:159, 0, 22773, 126001, 114572, 1838, 0, 0, 9w4d, 8
2001:578:2800:0:172:22:77:160, 0, 22773, 126009, 114560, 1838, 0, 0, 11w2d, 8
```